# Enable Caching for NGINX Proxy

Tags: nginx, cache

I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://serversforhackers.com/nginx-caching) to cache requests against [yt3.ggpht.com](http://yt3.ggpht.com/-C9gaunpPNo8/VYGWj4xT-uI/AAAAAAAAAGo/pUPfpvLF7Dc/w2120-fcrop64=1-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no/).

My configuration looks like:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone:10m inactive=60m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_cache my_zone;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass https://yt3.ggpht.com;
    }
}
```

If I  ran the link about against my local server, yt3.ggpht.com returns:

> The requested URL
>   `/-C9gaunpPNo8/VYGWj4xT-uI/AAAAAAAAAGo/pUPfpvLF7Dc/w2120-fcrop64=1-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no/`
>   was not found on this server.  That’s all we know.

If I remove the `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` line, my requests pass, but caching does not work.

Why doesn't it work, if I set `Host` (It does, if I run requests against another dummy-ngnix remote server).

And also, why is the parameter `Host` necessary to enable caching?